# Comma between two statements in Python 3 on a single line

Tags: python-3.x

I was reading through some source code and came across two statements separated by a comma on a single line. See code below.

```py
plt.plot(), plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

I believe this is something like a tuple but it is not unpacked over an assignment. Am I correct?

Comment: This is a tuple, yes, it's not unpacked or assigned. If you're writing this in a Jupyter notebook, it's assumend you want the result printed. If you want 2 commands run on one line without this, use a semicolon instead of a comma

Comment: Try 'print( _ )' , maybe is assigned there